# Convert http request / add a function in case of success. ::Typescript & Angular2

Tags: javascript, http, angular, asynchronous, typescript

I have a http request:

```
private getValues() {
  this._watchlistElements.map(v =>
    this.http.get('http://localhost/getValue/' + v.xid)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this._values.push(res.json());
    }));
};
```

And in **case of success**, I want to make one line code:

`this.vars.map((v,i) => v.push(this._values[i].value));`

**My question is** in normal ajax it would be like `.success: function(){}`

How to convert my code into something like this?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

```
private getValues() {
  this._watchlistElements.map(v =>
    this.http.get('http://localhost/getValue/' + v.xid)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this._values.push(res.json());
      })).then(console.log());
};
```

Angular2 is unable to resolve the `then` variable. What have I to import into component to make it work?

Comment: Angular's $http supports promises. Your approach would be something like $http.get(url).then(successFunction).catch(errorFunction);

Comment: @fubbe Thanks, would u like to make a full answer?

Answer (score 1):

The http function uses observables.
You can do something like this:

```
 private getValues() {
      this._watchlistElements.map(v =>
        this.http.get('http://localhost/getValue/' + v.xid).map(res=>res.json())
          .subscribe(res => {
           //success
          },
         error=>{
             //error logic
          });
      }
```

If you want to use only promises,

```
private getValues() {
  this._watchlistElements.map(v =>
    this.http.get('http://localhost/getValue/' + v.xid)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res=>{res.json()}).catch(errorFunction);
};
```